# What is the syntax of DISPLAY environment variable?

Tags: linux, x11

I'm writing program in x86-64 assembly for linux that will create X11 window using only system calls invoked with *syscall* instruction. Based on the content of the DISPLAY environment variable I have to create either tcp or unix socket. In linux manual "man 7 X" it is written that :

> The hostname part of the display name should be the empty string.  For example:  :0, :1, and :0.1.  The most efficient local transport will be chosen.

However I compiled C code example from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X_Window_Programming/XCB and ran compiled executable in GDB with changed DISPLAY environment variable. When I change DISPLAY environment variable from DISPLAY=:0 to DISPLAY=unix:0 or DISPLAY=unix/:0 or DISPLAY=unix/abc:0 window is still created. Is linux manual wrong and what is real syntax of DISPLAY environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: X11 can run over multiple transport. The comment is related to 'local' connection.

Long Answer:

The quote that you include refers to 'local' connection. The X11 system can run over few tarnsport layers. On my system:

```
       local
               The hostname part of the display name should be the empty string.  For example:  :0, :1, and :0.1.  The most effi‐
               cient local transport will be chosen.

       TCPIP
               The hostname part of the display name should be the server machine's hostname or IP address.  Full Internet names,
               abbreviated names, IPv4 addresses, and IPv6 addresses are all allowed.  For  example:  x.org:0,  expo:0,  [::1]:0,
               198.112.45.11:0, bigmachine:1, and hydra:0.1.
```

Also, many systems support running over unix sockets, which had (at least in the past) more efficient that TCP connections.